# Why do we define the pants complex and the pants decomposition?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, mapping-class-groups, surfaces

Why do we define the pants complex?

I learned for the first time in [A Presentation for the mapping class group of a closed orientable surface](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/Papers/MCGpresentation.pdf) (by A. Hatcher and W. Thurston)
that we have definition of pants complex and pants decomposition.

What is the application of the pants complex (in the above paper this called cut system)? Why do we define the pants complex and the pants decomposition?

Comment: Cutting a compact surface, perhaps with boundary, into pairs of pants reduces many problems to the study of a single compact surface with boundary (a "pair of pants") and a problem of gluing compact surfaces with boundary together.

Comment: @BenMcKay .can you tell me those problems ? how can i find the list of problems that we can solve them with pairs of pants ?

Comment: There are applications to construct coordinates on Teichmueller space, and to metrics on moduli spaces of algebraic curves, and to topological quantum field theories more generally, described in the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_of_pants_(mathematics).

Comment: The cited paper contains a famous application of the pants complex: the computation of presentations for mapping class groups. Note that the fact that the pants complex is simply connected plays a crucial role in the computation. So it seems to me that the answer is already contained in the question. For more applications, if you have access to MathSciNet you could look at the (143) papers that cite Hatcher--Thurston.

Comment: @HJRW . Why simply connectedness of pants complex is is important in the above paper?

Comment: @Usa I feel the best way to answer both your original question and your follow-up in the comments is to read the paper of Hatcher and Thurston and see (a) what the pants complex is used for (as HJRW suggests), and (b) how the authors use simple-connectedness in the argument (they use this fact, Theorem 1.1, in the proof of Theorem 2.2).

Comment: @Usa: I also think that you'll appreciate it more if you read the paper, but here's a vague philosophical idea: if you have a group $G$ acting on a space $X$, then you can often use that action to find generators for $G$ if $X$ is connected and to find relations if $X$ is $1$-connected.  This pattern continues for things like calculating the homology of $G$: if $X$ is $k$-connected, you can often use it to calculate the homology up to degree $k$.

Answer (score 1):

Cut systems are not the same as pants decompositions.  The former are defined in section one of the paper and consist of $g$ curves.  The later are defined in the appendix (and there called "markings") and consist of $3g - 3$ curves.

To add another answer to the ones given in the comments: cutting a complicated thing into simpler pieces is a useful technique in topology, in mathematics, and life generally.  Hatcher and Thurston use cut systems to reduce their problem (of presenting the mapping class group) to an easier problem (of presenting the spherical braid group).  This is spelled out in the first sentence of the second paragraph of their paper:

> From these properties of cut systems it is a routine matter to read
> off a finite presentation for the mapping class group of $M$, the group
> of isotopy classes of orientation preserving self-diffeomorphisms of
> $M$.